# Making a conversation visible only to from_id and to_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to make my conversation only be viewed by the sender and receiver. Any help or point in direction would be appreciated.

Conversation Controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def index

   @conversations = Conversation.all
   #@conversation = current_user.conversation.from_id + @user.conversation.to_id
   #@conversations = current_user.messages.find(params[:id])
   #@conversations = current_user && @user != current_user
   #@conversations = Conversation.find(current_user).last
   #@conversations = from.id + to.id
  end
```

Conversation Model

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base

 validates :to_id, :from_id, presence: true

 belongs_to :to, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :from, class_name: "User"
 has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :conversation

 def self.exist_with?(user, current_user)
  if Conversation.where(from_id: user.id ,to_id: current_user.id).blank? &&
     Conversation.where(from_id: current_user.id, to_id: user.id).blank?
     return false   
  else
    return true
  end
 end

 def self.find_conversation(user, current_user)
  conversation = Conversation.where(from_id: user.id ,to_id: current_user.id) +
                 Conversation.where(from_id: current_user.id, to_id: user.id)
  conversation.first
 end
end
```

Conversation Index.html.erb

```
<h1 class="message"> Messages </h1>

<ul>
 <% @conversations.reverse.each do |conversation| %>
  <li class="cmessages"> 
   <%= image_tag conversation.to.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => "username-picture" %>
   <%= link_to conversation.to.user_name, "/conversations/#{ conversation.id }", :class => "username" %>
   <%= time_ago_in_words(conversation.created_at) %> ago
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Conversation Schema

```
create_table "conversations", force: true do |t|
 t.integer  "to_id"
 t.integer  "from_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

If there is something missing please notify me and I will include any file information that might be missing in order to solve this problem. Again thank you for everyone help and point in the right direction for my problem. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @conversations = Conversation.where("from_id = :user OR to_id = :user", user: current_user.id)
  end
```

To avoid filling model logic into the controller, create method or scope in the model

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.accessible_by(user)
    where("from_id = :user OR to_id = :user", user: user.id)
  end
end
```

and reuse it in the controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @conversations = Conversation.accessible_by(current_user)
  end
```

Also note that the following query

```
where("from_id = :user OR to_id = :user", user: user.id)
```

it's just a shortcut for

```
where("from_id = ? OR to_id = ?", user.id, user.id)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much for explaining the query from before as well. Really appreciate the help you've given me.